# Ignore error while generating JS AST using ESPIRMA

Tags: javascript, node.js, esprima

How to instruct esprima to continue generating AST even if there are syntax errors in the JS file?

Example:

```
var x = ; // syntax error
var y = 5;
x = y;
```

The normal esprima output (even when enabling tolerant mode):

> description: 'Unexpected token ;'

Comment: Why would you want the code to continue being generated if there are errors? That would cause errors down the line (logic errors) apart from the syntax errors initially being caused by the incorrect JS programming.

Comment: doing one research on more than 100k js files and it is ok to skip errors and get into the important part of the JS file

Comment: "important part" every part is important, you could miss a variable used in every other line of the program. Your logic is fundamentally flawed, as a syntax error is intended to prevent logic errors, so it is illogical to ignore it.

Comment: Your general statement is defin true but not in my specific case I havr which is out of the topic to discuss it.

Comment: Also, what I want is to continue in generating and report the error... currently it throws exception with no AST output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it is not possible with ESPIRMA.
However, I could achieve that using acorn-loose which will generate the same AST structure.